# Are sentences number 3 and 4 grammatical?

Tags: word-order, grammaticality-in-context

We can say these two sentences.

> 1. He is a better person than him.
> 2. A person better than him should behave excellently.

My question is, can we swap them like this?

> 3. He is a person better than him.
> 4. Better person than him should behave excellently.

I think sentence 4 is wrong and sentence 3 is correct. Am I right? If not, why not?

Comment: Sentence 2 is wrong, to begin with, which will doubtless throw you off; something like "People better than him…" or "A person better than him…". Either way, it sounds odd.

Comment: But I see that people use sentences like "people in Canada" with "who are" deleted. "People (who are) in Canada." I thought it worked in the same way. " A person (who is) better than him."

Comment: It works if you use "someone" to introduce the concept of "a particular individual from the set that satisfies this condition" ("better than him"). Otherwise, no, "person", singular, simply isn't used that way. "People", plural, is.

Comment: Word "people" can be used with it? Like "people better than him"? Also, is it grammatically wrong?

Comment: Or is it just that most of us do not use it that way?

Comment: The distinction between "grammatically wrong" and "people don't use it that way, ever" doesn't really exist. They mean the same thing. But yes, "People better than him…" is fine.

Comment: I don't understand. Why people is ok and person is not? Would it be fine for you to move it to chat by the way?

Comment: I'd have no problem with that, but I think you'd have to be registered. But briefly, I believe that the difference is whether they are referring to more than one person who might satisfy the condition; the only way to specify a *single* person also satisfying a condition using that structure is to say "someone", to pick one at random from the multiple that might be eligible.

Comment: It says not yet enough to chat... anyway, thank you for your generosity :) . So whenever there is word "person" in that type of structure, would I have to change it to someone? For example: Not "Person in Brazil", but "someone in Brazil"?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: "Good grief, I was beginning to sound like a person desperate for a date..." It's the quotation from the Google book. Why did author use word "person" instead of "someone"? Is there a difference between this and my example?

Comment: Yes. They said "a person", not just "person". Either works, as I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: Oh...  the article.. it always gets me... so are sentences number three and four correct if I change it to "a person"?